# How to add trailing newline to handlebars each?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have this pattern all over my app where I want a trailing newline to my each blocks if there are any elements in the array. So I can do things like:

```
{{#each array}}
{{value}}
{{#if @last}}

{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

or with handlebars-helpers package I can use any:

```
{{#any array}}
{{#each array}}
{{value}}
{{/each}}

{{/any}}
```

However in my app the templates are visible to the customer and it's getting ugly as I prolifirate the extra boilerplate all over my template code.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

I was hoping handlebars had a whitespace control character I could take advantage of or at the least be able to turn that 'if' block into a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do that using CSS. Consider:

Template:

```
<div class='array-output-wrapper {{#if array}}with-items{{/if}}'>
    {{#each array}}
        {{value}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.array-output-wrapper.with-items:after {
    display: block;
    content: '\00a0'; // entity code for $nbsp;
}
```

It increases readability, as *enter-hit-generated* new line is easily overlooked.

Comment: I like it, however for my use case I am outputting to non-html text files.

Comment: Right. I will think of something else then.